# Wireless, low profile UK keyboard & mouse with backslash

Tags: keyboards, mice

I'm looking for the perfect keyboard and mouse. This is what perfect means for me:

- Normal shape, not interested in ergonomic curves, foldable etc.
- Slim and light keyboard & mouse
- Low profile keys
- Wireless, with both keyboard and mouse working off a single USB dongle
- Rechargeable would be nice, but not essential
- Traditional UK keyboard layout. The most important part is I want a "\" key between the "Shift" and the "z"

I thought Jelly Comb basically did what I want, in something like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Jelly-Comb-Wireless-Rechargeable-Keyboard-Silver-White/dp/B07R8P4VHT/), but alas, they've put the "\" key above "Enter". So many keyboards seem to either do that or put "\" as a function option on the "z".

I also ordered [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07T13FH28/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00), which has the layout I'm looking for, but it's just too big and clunky, the keys are too high profile. I don't like typing on it at all.

Anyone know of such a slim, low-profile wireless keyboard & mouse combo?

Comment: I've ordered https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07XFFL36S for now, hopefully it'll be what I want. I'll post an answer if it is.

Comment: Would you be open to mechanical key switches or just rubber domes?